# Is Adi Shankaracharya's commentary on the Adhyatma Patala available online in English?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, translation-request, adi-shankaracharya, dharma-shastras

It is well-known that Adi Shankaracharya wrote commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita, the Upanishada, the Brahma Sutras, and the Vishnu Sahasranamam.  But there's one commentary that's not as well known.

The Apastamba Dharma Sutras primarily discuss the rules of right and wrong, like any Dharma Shastra.  But [Patala 8](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0225.htm) of the Apastamba Dharma Sutras, known as the Adhyatma Patala, discusses an entirely different subject, namely the nature of the Atma within:

> Kanda 1
>
> 1. He shall employ the means which tend to the acquisition of (the knowledge of) the Âtman, which are attended by the consequent (destruction of the passions, and) which prevent the wandering (of the mind from its object, and fix it on the contemplation of the Âtman).
> 2. There is no higher (object) than the attainment of (the knowledge of the) Âtman.
> 3. We shall quote the verses (from the Veda) which refer to the attainment of (the knowledge of) the Âtman.
> 4. All living creatures are the dwelling of him who lies enveloped in matter, who is immortal and who is spotless. Those become immortal who worship him who is immovable and lives in a movable dwelling.
> 5. Despising all that which in this world is called an object (of the senses) a wise man shall strive after the (knowledge of the) Âtman.
> 6. O pupil, I, who had not recognised in my own self the great self-luminous, universal, (absolutely) free Âtman, which must be obtained without the mediation of anything else, desired (to find) it in others (the senses). (But now as I have obtained the pure knowledge, I do so no more.) Therefore follow thou also this good road that leads to welfare (salvation), and not the one that leads into misfortune (new births).
> 7. It is he who is the eternal part in all creatures, whose essence is wisdom, who is immortal, unchangeable, destitute of limbs, of voice, of the (subtle) body, (even) of touch, exceedingly pure; he is the universe, he is the highest goal; (he dwells in the middle of the body as) the Vishuvat day is (the middle of a Sattra-sacrifice); he, indeed, is (accessible to all) like a town intersected by many streets.
> 8. He who meditates on him, and everywhere and always lives according to his (commandments), and who, full of devotion, sees him who is difficult to be seen and subtle, will rejoice in (his) heaven.
>
> Kanda 2
>
> 1. That Brâhmana, who is wise and recognises all creatures to be in the Âtman, who pondering (thereon) does not become bewildered, and who recognises the Âtman in every (created) thing, shines, indeed, in heaven.
> 2. He, who is intelligence itself and subtler than the thread of the lotus-fibre, pervades the universe, and who, unchangeable and larger than the earth, contains the universe; he, who is different from the knowledge of this world, obtained by the senses and identical with its objects, possesses the highest (form consisting of absolute knowledge). From him, who divides himself, spring all (created) bodies. He is the primary cause, he is eternal, he is unchangeable.
> 3. But the eradication of the faults is brought about in this life by the means (called Yoga). A wise man who has eradicated the (faults) which destroy the creatures, obtains salvation.
> 4. Now we will enumerate the faults which tend to destroy the creatures.
> 5. (These are) anger, exultation, grumbling, covetousness, perplexity, doing injury, hypocrisy, lying, gluttony, calumny, envy, lust, secret hatred, neglect to keep the senses in subjection, neglect to concentrate the mind. The eradication of these (faults) takes place through the means of (salvation called) Yoga.
> 6. Freedom from anger, from exultation, from grumbling, from covetousness, from perplexity, from hypocrisy (and) hurtfulness; truthfulness, moderation in eating, silencing a slander, freedom from envy, self-denying liberality, avoiding to accept gifts, uprightness, affability, extinction of the passions, subjection of the senses, peace with all created beings, concentration (of the mind on the contemplation of the Âtman), regulation of one's conduct according to that of the Âryas, peacefulness and contentedness;--these (good qualities) have been settled by the agreement (of the wise) for all (the four) orders; he who, according to the precepts of the sacred law, practises these, enters the universal soul.

Adi Shankaracharya saw the philosophical teachings mentioned in this chapter as important enough that he references it in his Brahma Sutra Bhashya, and he wrote a commentary on it, the Adhyatma Patala Bhashya.  My question is, is the Adhyatma Patala Bhashya available online in English?

So far I've come across two English translations of the Adhyatma Patala Bhashya:

1. R.S Narasimhan's [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Yoga_of_Right_Living_for_Self_realisatio.html?id=FVKsGAAACAAJ) "Yoga of right living for self-realisation : a free rendering of Adhyatma patala of Apastamba dharma sutra with commentary of Adi Sankara", which seems to be out of print.
2. Trevor Legget's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0710087020) "Chapter of the Self", which also seems to be out of print but is available used from various third-party sellers.

But are there any online translations?